# How to combine multiple conditions in one regex expression - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is an example I have http://regexr.com/3dii7

I want to delete everything that in parentheses(`<>` and `{}`) except that ends on `|b}` and `|URL}`

The first working pattern is `{.*[^\\|b]}`

The second working pattern is `{(((?!\|URL).)*?)}`

And the third `<.*>`

How can I combine them together in one `preg_replace()` call?

Shouldn't be deleted

```
{jelly3|b}
{jelly3|URL}
{文字列|b}
{文字列|URL}
```

I've tried `{.*[^\\|b]}|{(((?!\|URL).)*?)}|<.*>` but it doesn't work, it deletes every {}. Here is the link http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fVF

Comment: Are you sure your patterns are working? Have you tested with multiple groups of parentheses in one line? Also the second pattern doesn't match `{a|URL|hello}`, but according to your description it should.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske Yes, you're right, thank you for pointing it out. I have to fix it.

Comment: You can match multiple expressions by combining them with `|`. `xxx|yyy` matches either `xxx` or `yyy`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your comment. I've tried it :) I updated my question.

Comment: @whitesiroi if there are no nested parentheses, no quoted parentheses and  parentheses are always balanced [`{[^}]*+(?<!\|URL)(?<!\|b)}|<[^>]*+>`](https://regex101.com/r/aK2iX7/1) will work.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske Thank you very much Sebastian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two negative lookaheads seems to work in this case:

```
<.*>|\{(?!.*\|URL\})(?!.*\|b\}).*\}
```

Or with only 1 negative lookahead :

```
<.*>|\{(?!.*\|(?:URL|b)\}).*\}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate for your help.

Comment: This will give [interesting results](https://regex101.com/r/sV1mT3/1) for lines with multiple groups. Not sure if you have to consider this.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske Interesting :) Thank you for your help. I definitely have to write some test code.

Comment: For lines with multiple groups it's indeed a bit trickier.  But it works if the .* are replaced by [^}]. Like : `<.*>|\{(?![^}]*\|(?:URL|b)\})[^}]*\}`